# Get Query String value containing spaces

Tags: html, asp.net

My url with query string is:

```
http://testpage.aspx?PHONENUMBER=9991234567&CALLBACK_REASON=1st Attempt - First Contact for FNOL
```

i'm trying to get values as:

```
PHONENUMBER= (this.Request["PHONENUMBER"] == null) ? "-" : this.Request["PHONENUMBER"];

CALLBACK_REASON = (this.Request["CALLBACK_REASON"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["CALLBACK_REASON"];
```

Here i'm unable to get CALLBACK_REASON values. Any help would be grt.

Comment: Unable to get CALLBACK_REASON? Does it throw an exception, do you get no value, do you get an incorrect value? You need to give more detail...

Comment: "1st Attempt - First Contact for FNOL" this  is the value dat i get in url. I need to get this value but as if nw i'm getting nothing ie "".

Comment: What value do you get for PHONENUMBER?

Comment: i'm able to get PHONENUMBER=9991234567 similarly  i need to get CALLBACK_REASON=1st Attempt - First Contact for FNOL.

Comment: i'm getting dat url from third party !!! so can it be done without encoding???

Comment: you should contact the third party to properly encode the url. If you can't try calling Request.Query to get the full querystring, and then manually break the string to get callback_reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a URL with [the spaces encoded](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201006/be_careful_with_non-ascii_characters_in_urls/) (it will have to look like this):

```
http://testpage.aspx?PHONENUMBER=9991234567&CALLBACK_REASON=1st%20Attempt%20-%20First%20Contact%20for%20FNOL
```

Then to read back the values, simply use this code...

```
PHONENUMBER= (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Request["PHONENUMBER"]) ? "-" : Server.UrlDecode(this.Request["PHONENUMBER"]);

CALLBACK_REASON = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Request["CALLBACK_REASON"]) ? string.Empty : Server.UrlDecode(this.Request["CALLBACK_REASON"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) the values you put in the URI.